# Is it possible to edit Crystal Reports XI files (*.rpt) in Crystal Reports 2011?

Tags: crystal-reports, format, report

Latest version, CR 2011: http://www.dustin.se/crystal-reports-2011-win-lic-3-9-users/product/5010602194

Need to edit files created in this version CR XI (2005, no longer for sale):
http://www.dustin.se/crystal-reports-xi-professional-win-eng-cd/product/5010078615

Does anybody know if there's an "Save as CR XI-report" option in the latest version?

The file format must remain in CR XI-format when edit is done.

Thanks
/Roland

Answer (score 0):

In CR2008 there is no option to save as previous .rpt versions so I would assume the same goes for 2011, although I have never used it. In [this thread](http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2069868&tstart=0), SAP seems to confirm that "there will never be" a save-as option for previous versions' filetypes.

From their site:

```
For forward compatibility, RPT files authored in SAP Crystal Reports 2011 can
be opened with the following older versions of Crystal Reports:
• SAP Crystal Reports 2008
• Crystal Reports XI
This includes the COM- and .NET-based runtime engines shipped with these
products.
New features in SAP Crystal Reports 2011 will be ignored by the older versions
of the runtime engines.
```

That sounds like a good way of getting into trouble. My advice is instead try to get your hands on a copy of CRXI instead of putting yourself through the potential headaches of dealing with versioning bugs.