# Features in Crystal Reports 2011 that could cause failure in a Crystal XI reader

Tags: crystal-reports, version, crystal-reports-xi, forward-compatibility

I've developed a report in Crystal Reports 2011 (v14), and I need to get it to work in an application that's built on the reader for Crystal Reports XI (v11). I'm working on procuring XI, so I can adapt the report there, but in the mean time, it would be nice if I could just get the report as developed in 2011 to work. I was hoping this would work due to the forward compatibility note quoted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8124939/179).

When I try to run my report in the XI-based application, I get

> ERROR: -2147206429
>
> Invalid TLV Record.
>
> In module: Crystal Reports ActiveX Designer

My suspicion is that my report is using some feature in 2011 that's not present in XI and somehow stumping the XI reader engine. When I took a report that had been developed in XI and opened and saved it in 2011, it opened with no trouble in XI.

What features are there in 2011 and not XI that could be tripping me up here? What should I check my report for to make it most likely that it will run in XI?

UPDATE:
I tried rebuilding my report, one feature at a time, to see when the error kicks in on XI. It does as soon as I make a parameter's prompt group a dynamic list that queries a stored procedure or a table, even if I don't set any special characteristics of the prompt group. Given that dynamic parameter prompt groups came in with XI, shouldn't this work?

Comment: I don't recall being able to use a stored procedure for a dynamic prompt in the past- i think you could only use columns in your dataset.

Comment: @LeeTickett, in this case, the dataset consists of multiple stored procedures - a main one, with the data in it, and supplementary ones to support the prompt groups. The dynamic prompt group is just hitting a column of one of the stored procedures, just like the report results are.

Comment: ... and I still have the problem when I use a supplementary table instead of a supplementary stored procedure as the source for the dynamic list.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many- and as you state- i've always found them to be fully backward compatible.

The main things that spring to mind are the dynamic sort control and the ability to create optional parameters.

If you wish to attach the report I can try opening/saving/checking.

Comment: I'm not using dynamic sort control, and I tried making mandatory all parameters that were optional, but that didn't help. Thanks very much for offering to help! Would you be able to test this aspect of the report without being able to connect to the database it connects to? I'm using dynamic lists of values for most parameters, generated by calling stored procedures in the DB.